How can I find out how many app users I have and also how many have opted in to receive push notifications? Thanks
I'm looking for total number of app users and also total number of users that have opted in to receive push notifications.
I've tried the 'Messaging' section and looked at Topics and Segments but the totals don't seem to add up.
Any guidance is appreciated.
